# Accessing POST data in Django form

Tags: python, django

I have been using [this site](http://jacobian.org/writing/dynamic-form-generation/) as an example of how to make a dynamic form in Django. In his view he uses

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
```

to pass the data into the form and in the form constructor he uses

```
extra = kwargs.pop('extra')
```

to access the POST data. I tried to do something similar with my view:

```
def custom_report(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        form=CustomQueryConstraintForm(request.POST)
    else:
        form=CustomQueryConstraintForm()
    return render(request, 'frontend/custom_report.html', {'form':form})
```

In my form constructor I printed `args` and `kwargs` and found that `kwargs` is empty and `args` is a tuple containing the `QueryDict` that in turn contains the POST data. If I try instead to use `form=CustomQueryConstraintForm(**request.POST)`, each element in `kwargs` is a list containing the value of the field as its only element. Am I doing something wrong here? If not, is there a more elegant way of accessing the data than `args[0][element_name][0]`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is expected behavior for forms: the POST data you pass into the form is the first argument, args[0] and not a keyword argument. What are you looking for?

```
data = args[0]
print data['my_field']
```

> and in the form constructor he uses
>   extra = kwargs.pop('extra') to access
>   the POST data.

`kwargs.pop('extra')` is not getting POST data. It is a list of questions associated with that given user -- some scenario given by the author that the "marketing department" handed you.

In any case, if you need to access the post data at any point in a form, I find `self.data` the cleanest which is set in `forms.__init__`.

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.data['my_field']
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me. I am still confused about why the POST data showed up in `kwargs` in the example but not in my code.

Comment: Which example are you talking about? The example in the post you linked to says extra is a list of strings, not POST data. If you want post data as a kwarg, just pass in `mykwarg=request.POST` then `kwargs.pop('mykwarg')` in your `__init__` function.

Comment: Thanks for pointing `self.data` which I was looking for: I am using a dynamic HTML in which input fields are added on the fly, and accessing the `POST` is hence necessary (or I should maintain a hidden field).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctltly, after a POST request you are trying to redisplay the same form page in which the form fields are filled, right? If yes, this is what you need:

```
form = CustomQueryConstraintForm(initial=request.POST)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also access the form data through the `cleaned_data` dictionary after using the `is_valid()` method. Like this:

```
jobForm = JobForm(request.POST)
jobForm.is_valid()
jobForm.cleaned_data
```

it's a dictionary of the values that have been entered into the form.