# how to update(calculate) a specific field if the object exists django

Tags: python, mysql, django, insert-update

i made a project for a store , and i want to prevent from duplicate products , if the product doesnt exists then insert it into the database , but otherwise if it doesn't then just update field(quantity)

models.py

```
class Item(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Product,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
```

for example we have inserted this data:

```
 item = mouse , quantity = 20
```

then we add this data later

```
 item = mouse , quantity = 30
```

now what i try to whenever the item exists , just update the quantity like this (20 + 30 ) = 50 , add the previous quantity with new quantity to get total number of quantities ! is it possible please ?
i've read some articles about `get_or_create` and `update_or_create` but still i dont have any idea how it work in my case !?

views.py

```
def createNewProduct(request):
   form = ItemForm()
   if request.method == 'POST':
       form = ItemForm(request.POST)
       if form.is_valid():           
            form.save()

   return render(request,'temp/add_item.html',{'form':form})
```

forms.py

```
class ItemForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ['item','quantity']
```

thank you for your suggestion
regards ..

Comment: On MySQL level this is `INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/53200609/10138734 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/12926611/10138734 and so on..

Comment: Pls add your code of `ItemForm`. However, overriding `create` and `update` in `ItemForm` can be an approach. You can also override `validate` and adjust your form data to get what you would like.

Comment: @KlimBim i add `ItemForm`

Comment: @Akina no , sorry , overwrite

Comment: non of them work in my case , because i dont want to just overwrite my current data , i need something like this > quantity = old quantity data + new quantity data

Comment: *i dont want to just overwrite my current data , i need something like this* Your "this" is data overwriting.

Comment: @Akina whats wrong with that text !?

Comment: *quantity = old quantity data + new quantity data* - this overwrites old value with new one, is it? This is one that `INSERT ... ODKU` performs. Precisely.

Comment: yes , replace the old data with (old quantity + new inserted quantity

Comment: @Akina do you have any idea how to implement it in django please

Comment: I don't use Django, so I cannot. But [@Klim Bim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6897919/klim-bim) gives you the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67296460/10138734) (which maybe needs in minimal debugging in your particular environment, it seems)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you can use `update_or_create`. However, this method will override your current data if you do a PUT. Your `quantity` will be overriden and will not be like this `quantity+=new_quantity`.

Therefore, you must override `save()` in `ItemForm` [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method)

```py
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.instance is None
       # custom POST operation or `return super().save(*args, **kwargs)`
    else:   
       self.instance.quantity = self.instance.quantity + self.cleaned_data.get('quantity')
       # further PUT operation
       instance.save()
    ...
```

`self.data` and `self.instance` comes from `BaseModelForm`

Comment: thank you for your idea , but it returns `unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType'
`

Comment: it returns None !

Comment: @HunarMohammed:  Does `self.data` have any data ? If not, what does `self.cleaned_data` contain? A further approach can be to override `__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)` in your form. For instance, ```class MyForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.data['my_field']```. [similar querstion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6523183/accessing-post-data-in-django-form)

Comment: and `instance.quantity` returns the new data as well instead of the old value , and i had to add self. in front of all instances.quantity

Comment: `self.cleaned_data`  returns the new inserted value ! non of them return the old data

Comment: thank you i solved `        else:
            Item.objects.filter(item__name=self.instance.item).update(quantity=F('quantity') + self.instance.quantity)
`